# Modify comments_popup_link output

Tags: theme-development, themes, comments

The following function generates the plain output eg. No comments, 1 comment etc.

```
comments_popup_link(
    __( 'No comments', 'textdomain' ), 
    __( '1 Comment', 'textdomain' ), 
    __( '% Comments', 'textdomain' ) 
);
```

However I want to wrap the first word/number in an html tag, to get following output:

```
<span>No</span> comments
<span>1</span> comment
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `__( 'No comments', 'textdomain' )` with  `__( '<span>No</span> comments', 'textdomain' )`, there is nothing that stops you to do it.

In general, HTML inside translatable strings are not recommended but if you **really** need the span tags, you have not other choice to add them server side. I strongly recommend to think why do you need those `<span>` and investigate if you can archive the same result without them.

More in [i18n for WordPress Developers: HTML in translatable strings](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#HTML)